# didn't set CLASSPATH variable why program aslo can run

Tags: java, classpath

I installed JDK7 in my computer. I just specified the path like that:

[image]

I didn't set CLASSPATH.

I writed a test program , the program like that:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Hello_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(File.separator);
    }
}
```

I complied it and runned it like that:

[image]

According the result, we could see that it didn't have any error.I was confused. I didn't set CLASSPATH, according the ORACLE DOC, it said:

> The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the
>   current directory is searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH
>   variable or the -cp command line switch overrides this value.

if i didn't set CLASSPATH variable, the default class path is ".", so when I compiled Hello_1.java it would only search java.io.File in current directory, there nothing about the java.io.File, so it would thrown exception. But why it worked well?

Comment: Java find its core libraries (rt.jar) regardless of set classpath. Indeed i never set CLASSPATH, i prefer to have proper -cp for every application, if needed

Comment: I installed JDK7 I find in c:\program files\java there has two rt.jar, one is placed in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib, other is placed in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib, for this, which is used, how javac.exe or java.exe decided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath is used to search for your own classes, but the built-in class library is available automatically without needing to be added to the classpath.  So `Hello_1` is found on the default classpath (the current directory) and `java.io.File` is found in the built-in class library.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the path to JDK bin in the PATH variable. So now your OS know java/javac as the commands and hence you can run your code. Classpath comes into picture if your source code or libraries are in some other directory than your current directory.